# Apache rewrite not finding path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex

I am trying to rewrite an internal path for specific requests. I have the following URL: http://192.168.0.100/iw/cci/meta/no-injection/iw-mount/default/main/intranet/infozone/pab/WORKAREA/content/htdocs/english/r1713497/pa/abc.html

That web page has some Server Side Includes. However this is a web content management system so the files being included reside elsewhere. The SSI line is `<!--#include virtual="/wxt/wxt40/head.htm" -->`. There is also an alias set up for `iw-mount`. So I assume that it will try to find that include at http://192.168.0.100/iw/cci/meta/no-injection/iw-mount/wxt/wxt40/head.htm. I need to remap it to find it at http://192.168.0.100/iw/cci/meta/no-injection/iw-mount/default/main/common/wxt/WORKAREA/content/htdocs/wxt/wxt40/head.htm.

So I have tried some different combinations for the rewrite with no luck. Here is the last one I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:url} ^/iw-mount/.*?/wxt.*$
RewriteRule ^(/iw-mount/).*?(/wxt.*$) $1default/main/common/wxt/WORKAREA/content/htdocs$2
```

I am pretty good with understanding Regex but I think it is my limited understanding of what Apache rewrite actually does that may be my problem. I read over the docs and looked at examples but they are not clear. So i guess I have 2 qestions:

1. Am I rewriting URLs or local paths?
2. Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my rewrite rule above?